# error during sqoop data migration

Tags: oracle11g, hdfs, sqoop, ora-00936

I have one doubt. I am trying to pull data from oracle and want to push it into `HDFS` using `sqoop 1.4.6`.
The table which I want to migrate contains column named "`COMMENT`"(which is a reserved keyword in oracle), but when I tried to push table into `HDFS` using `sqoop`, the error occurred was:

> 15/09/30 14:52:49 ERROR db.DBRecordReader: Top level exception: 
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

I have tried by putting `\ and "` for this column as:
`"\"\"COMMENT\"\""` when I listed column names during query

so how to get this error fixed..

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am facing similiar issue, throwing SQLSyntaxError: Invalid Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use --query option for sqoop import.

eg: sqoop import --query "select COMMENT from Table_Name ....."